# "Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint" when executing a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure which inputs 3 parameters selected from a query. The first 2 stored procedure parameters are supposed to be `int` or `bigint`, but sql doesn't accept it and tell me it cannot convert type nvarchar to bigint.

So I changed the parameter types to `nvarchar` but now I get this error when executing a query within the stored procedure. I tried to convert `nvarchar` to `bigint` but it doesn't work even though the parameter values are numeric.

Here's how I'm executing the stored procedure:

```
[dbo].[InsertMultiChoiceList] [PatientRiskAssessmentQuestionsID], NetworkRiskAssessmentQuestionsID, Answer
```

The parameters being passed on look like these:

```
230124| 118 |COPD (Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease), Congestive Heart Failure (CHF), Sleep Apnea
```

Here the definition of my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertMultiChoiceList] 
    @PatientRiskAssessmentQuestionsID nvarchar(100), 
    @NetworkRiskAssessmentQuestionsID nvarchar(100), 
    @answer varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @XML AS XML
    DECLARE @Delimiter AS CHAR(1) =','

    SET @XML = CAST(('<X>'+REPLACE(@answer , @Delimiter ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') AS XML)

    DECLARE @temp TABLE (Answer Varchar(max))

    INSERT INTO @temp
        SELECT N.value('.', 'Varchar(max)') AS Answer 
        FROM @XML.nodes('X') AS T(N)

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[PatientRiskAssessmentQuestionsList](NetworkRiskAssessmentListID, PatientRiskAssessmentQuestionsID)
        SELECT
            [dbo].[fnc_GetNetworkRiskAssessmentList](LTRIM(RTRIM(q.Answer)), @NetworkRiskAssessmentQuestionsID, 'List') AS NetworkRiskAssessmentListID,
            @PatientRiskAssessmentQuestionsID
        FROM
            (SELECT Answer FROM @temp) q
        WHERE
            NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                        FROM PatientRiskAssessmentQuestionsList x 
                        WHERE x.NetworkRiskAssessmentListID = NetworkRiskAssessmentListID 
                          AND x.PatientRiskAssessmentQuestionsID = @PatientRiskAssessmentQuestionsID);
END
```

Here's the structure of the `PatientRiskAssessmentQuestionsList` table

[image]

Here's the script for `fnc_GetNetworkRiskAssessmentList`

```
ALTER function [dbo].[fnc_GetNetworkRiskAssessmentList]
    (@text varchar(max), 
     @networkriskquestionid bigint, 
     @type varchar(20)
    )
RETURNS BIGINT
AS
BEGIN
    declare @id bigint
    declare @questionid bigint
    declare @count int

    set @id = null
    set @questionid = null
    set @count = 0

    if(@type = 'List')
    begin
        select @count = Count(*) 
        from NetworkRiskAssessmentList mc 
        where mc.Answer = @text 
          and mc.NetworkRiskAssessmentQuestionsID = @networkriskquestionid

        if @count > 0
        begin
            select top(1) @questionid =  mc.NetworkRiskAssessmentListID 
            from NetworkRiskAssessmentList mc 
            where mc.Answer = @text 
              and mc.NetworkRiskAssessmentQuestionsID = @networkriskquestionid

            set @id =  @questionid
        end 
    end

    return @questionid
end
```

Comment: What is the structure of [PatientRiskAssessmentQuestionsList] table ?

Comment: check all the comparative statement. Anyone of them you are comparing a `BIGINT` with `NVARCHAR` ?

Comment: @Squirrel no there are no comparative statements in the script. even changing the stored procedure paramter type to bigint throws that error\

Comment: good, now  update the question via adding the code of fnc_GetNetworkRiskAssessmentList too.

Comment: Could you please post the code of fnc_GetNetworkRiskAssessmentList as well?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are trying to push a string value into the column `NetworkRiskAssessmentListID` which is actually `BIGINT` thus SQL doesn't allow the conversion.

Just a sample code to show you the issue

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
Patient BIGINT,
Network BIGINT
)

GO

DECLARE @Patient NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Network NVARCHAR(100)

SET @Patient = '1234'
SET @Network = 'List'

INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (@Patient,@Network)
```

Hope this helps, try changing the datatype of the table and give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

maybe your data has Enter character or Tab character so use code like below :

```
   DECLARE @XML AS XML

        DECLARE @Delimiter AS CHAR(1) =','

        SET @XML = CAST(('<X>'+REPLACE(@answer , @Delimiter ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') AS XML)

        DECLARE @temp TABLE (Answer Varchar(max))

        INSERT INTO @temp
        SELECT N.value('.', 'Varchar(max)') AS Answer FROM @XML.nodes('X') AS T(N)

        insert into [dbo].[PatientRiskAssessmentQuestionsList](NetworkRiskAssessmentListID, PatientRiskAssessmentQuestionsID)
        select
        [dbo].[fnc_GetNetworkRiskAssessmentList](LTRIM(RTRIM(q.Answer)), @NetworkRiskAssessmentQuestionsID, 'List') as NetworkRiskAssessmentListID,
        @PatientRiskAssessmentQuestionsID
        from
        (select cast(replace(replace(Answer, char(13), ''), char(10), '') as bigint) as Answer from @temp) q
        where not exists
        (
        select 1 from PatientRiskAssessmentQuestionsList x 
        where x.NetworkRiskAssessmentListID = NetworkRiskAssessmentListID and x.PatientRiskAssessmentQuestionsID = @PatientRiskAssessmentQuestionsID
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `PatientRiskAssessmentQuestionsID` value to `@PatientRiskAssessmentQuestionsID nvarchar(100)` parameter

Then you are using it in next code

```
select 1 from PatientRiskAssessmentQuestionsList x 
        where x.NetworkRiskAssessmentListID = NetworkRiskAssessmentListID 
        and x.PatientRiskAssessmentQuestionsID = @PatientRiskAssessmentQuestionsID
```

so the issue in the `AND` condition, here

```
and x.PatientRiskAssessmentQuestionsID = 'PatientRiskAssessmentQuestionsID'
```

x.PatientRiskAssessmentQuestionsID is `bigint`

and @PatientRiskAssessmentQuestionsID is `nvarchar (100)`

***its value
[`PatientRiskAssessmentQuestionsID`]***

so fix this one, and everything will be Ok.

Comment: How would I do the comparison because I'm not able to convert nvarchar to bigint type.